# Set option selection on mat-select to return placeholder after selection

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular6

I have the following Angular 6 code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pl9wkw

I'm tryin g to make the select dropdown reset to the place holder once a selection has been made.  I am using these two lines to try and reference the process:

```
@ViewChild('selectDropdown') selectDropdown: MatSelect;
```

and

```
this.selectDropdown.AppComponent.reset();
```

Alas, it does not work to set the dropdown back to the placeholder.  I know that it can be set back to the placeholder, because I have the blank `<mat-option></mat-option>` selectable, and once you do select it, it sets it back to the placeholder.

Any thoughts ... anyone.

Comment: So to be clear : when the user selects a value, what happens : the value is getting erased and replaced by the placeholder, or the placeholder is being replaced by the selected value ? Not very clear, sorry

Comment: @trichetriche Correct about the selected value, instead of showing up in the dropdown, it returns the value to none or the placeholder displaying.

Comment: So what do you do with the value ? Simply forget it ?

Comment: @trichetriche I do use the value, but then I need to forget it for being displayed in the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onChange method make the following change.

```
this.selectDropdown.value = [];
  // this.selectDropdown.AppComponent.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Onchange make following change

```
this.selectDropdown.value.reset();
```